# Dynamic .Range() function Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I was using the function .Range("some_cell") as follows:

```
For i = 1 to 100
   CurrentCell = 3 + i
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rage("JCurrentCell")
Next i
```

However, `Rage("JCurrentCell")` is not allowed, what can I do to dynamically change this range from (ex: J1, J2, J3, J4, ... Jn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `CurrentCell variable` outside quotation marks:

```
For i = 1 to 100
   CurrentCell = 3 + i
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & CurrentCell)
Next i
```

Pleas keep in mind, too:

1. use `Range()` object name, not `Rage()`
2. this line `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & CurrentCell)` is not complete at the moment, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I saw a piece of code here: `http://theexcelninja.wordpress.com/2012/10/14/excel-monte-carlo-simulation/` Is this person using a special `Progress.Progress.` function that is not available to everyone.

Comment: Sorry, one more questions, suppose I wanted to increment the `.Range("J")` to like J, K, L, M, N, ... what would be the best way to do so?

Comment: you could use `.offset` in this way: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & CurrentCell).Offset(0,X)` where X should increment: X=1>> column K, X=2>> column L, etc...

Comment: So if I did `.Offset(X,X)` it would also increment the row

Comment: One more question: If I wanted to increment the column whilst selecting a particular range, for example: `WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("D1:D"&var).Offset(0, i))`. I want to automatically increment each column to calculate average like: D1:Dvar, E1:Evar, F1:Fvar, ... where var is the final row number.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use cells

```
For i = 1 to 100
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 3, "J")
Next i
```